# Does Rails help in learning PHP Zend Framework

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, zend-framework

I'm starting to learn Zend Framework and it reminds of when I dabbled with Rails a while back. Does knowledge of Rails help with better understanding Zend and the whole controllers, model, views architecture? Zend feels to me like new PHP, Rails-style.

There are a lot of people talking about the steep learning curve, so I was thinking if Zend has indeed been influenced by Rails, I could learn a little bit of Rails then come back to Zend. Have you found learning Rails to be a better introduction to the world of Zend?

Comment: No, but learning Rails first will make you not want to use anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In my opinion, no. You should not learn Rails and then come back for Zend.**

Knowledge will help you everywhere. The more you know about programming the easier it will be to switch back and forth as all languages share a common ground: logic.

Your question is pretty subjective. Zend and Rails are based on a MVC model, sure they are. Do they share common ground, sure they do. Mastering one will help to master the other, no question. Will you be able to master Zend faster by learning Rails first and then switching to Zend... in my opinion, no.

This question is very subjective.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it will help. In a way. I have experience with both and Zend feels like unfinished version of Rails.

Don't get me wrong, there is more stuff in Zend than in Rails. Endless helpers, modules etc. But due to limitations of PHP everything is cumbersome and you have to type *a lot* even working on simple stuff.

But again this is subjective too. Just working on a Zend Framework project and wanted to see what other people say.